Modify Elasticsearch Bootstrap before Docker deployment
I am trying to run elasticsearch docker on google cloud run. Therefore, I pulled the image, tagged it to google artifact and pushed it.
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.13.4

docker tag docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.13.4 gcr.io/knowledgearchitects/docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.13.4

docker push gcr.io/knowledgearchitects/docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.13.4

I then try to run the container:
gcloud run deploy --image=gcr.io/knowledgearchitects/docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.13.4   --port=9200 --region=europe-west3 --allow-unauthenticated --platform=managed   --command=elasticsearch elasticsearch

The deployment fails, logs tell me this:
node validation exception
[1] bootstrap checks failed. You must address the points described in the following [1] lines before starting Elasticsearch. For more information see [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.13/bootstrap-checks.html]
bootstrap check failure [1] of [1]: max file descriptors [25000] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65535]; for more information see [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.13/_file_descriptor_check.html]

So my question is:
How can I edit the files that are referenced in the Elasticsearch documentation to change the bootstrap parameters?
I am relatively new to this and don't know where I need to connect to / where I am able to get into these files that I need to edit.
Is there a way to download the dockerfiles, edit them, and then republish them to my google artifact or something like that?
Or can I just add a command on deployed to pass these settings to the machine?
